# I am using twitter bootstrap, within laravel 5.3 and the collapse functionality is working locally perfectly, but not on the live server

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, deferred-loading

I have a headache of a problem I cannot seem to figure out, and have perused all the similar questions I can find to no avail.

I have a laravel 5.3 project, using twitter bootstrap 3.3.7, and jquery 3.1.1 minified.

Jquery is included via CDN.

The order of script loading is as follows, and they are loaded after the `<footer>`, inside the `<body>`, except for jquery which is loaded at the end of the `<head>`:

- Jquery
- app.js (laravel builds this, and it includes bootstrap)
- jquery UI
- my custom javacript file

Basically what this does, is there are 2 buttons. complete, and incomplete, we will call them A and B for now for simplicity. Each one is associated with a div. On page load all are hidden. When you click A, it will show div A and hide div B if it is not already hidden. When you click B, it will do the same but opposite.

The frustrating part? This works perfectly, with no errors, as expected, locally in my XAMPP local version of my web application. However when moved to the live server, in what I (thought) was an almost identical environment, it works 80% of the way.

When you click A, it will show A. (good)

When you click B, it will show B. (good)

When you click A or B, it is not hiding the opposite div as it does local.(bad)

So, for example you click A, then B, now you can see both A and B divs instead of just B.

Here is a snippet of relevant javascript. You can see the `$('#complete-'+eid).collapse('hide');` line for example, is the line that works locally but not on the server.

```
`$('.incomplete-btn, .complete-btn').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('has-response')){ 
        return;
    }
    var eid = $(this).attr('href').substr($(this).attr('href').length -1, 1);
    if($(this).hasClass('incomplete-btn')){
        if($(this).hasClass('lightgrey')){
            $(this).removeClass('lightgrey');
            $(this).addClass('orange')
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('lightgrey');
            $(this).removeClass('orange');
        }
        $('#complete-'+eid).collapse('hide');  //hide complete-btn
        $('#complete-btn-'+eid).addClass('lightgrey');
        $('#complete-btn-'+eid).removeClass('orange');
    }
    if($(this).hasClass('complete-btn')){
        if($(this).hasClass('lightgrey')){
            $(this).removeClass('lightgrey');
            $(this).addClass('blue')
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('lightgrey');
            $(this).removeClass('blue');
        }
        $('#incomplete-'+eid).collapse('hide');  //hide incomplete-btn
        $('#incomplete-btn-'+eid).addClass('lightgrey');
        $('#incomplete-btn-'+eid).removeClass('blue');
    }
});`
```

I have moved the scripts around, and I have examined them in dev tools to see when they are loaded. (I originally thought this had something to do with hidden divs not being accessible yet by the scripts or something like that). I played around with deferring script loads, or not hiding the divs on page load but none of this changed the problem I am having.

I am at a loss, will appreciate any insight.

Thanks all

Edit:

Fiddle of an example I made: https://jsfiddle.net/3o0Lfw7n/18/

Edit2:

Simplified code, still works locally, still does not work on server. No console errors on any browser or device. (It collapses/opens fine, the problem that keeps persisting is when you open one, the other one is not properly *closing*.

```
$(function() {
 $('.incomplete-btn, .complete-btn').on('click', function(){

    var clicked_btn = $(this);
    var eid = clicked_btn.attr('href').substr(clicked_btn.attr('href').length -1, 1);
    if(clicked_btn.hasClass('incomplete-btn')){
        $('#complete-'+eid).collapse('hide');
    }
    if(clicked_btn.hasClass('complete-btn')){
        $('#incomplete-'+eid).collapse('hide');
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but you should optimize your code by storing $(this) in a variable and accessing that variable. You should also queue the methods. Something like this: `var t = $(this); t.removeClass('lightgrey').addClass('blue');`

Comment: As for the question itself, you're not seeing any error messages in the console? Are you able to post a link to the actual page or even better, create a fiddle?

Comment: @VVV Thanks for the tip, I will make that change regarding $(this) and queue the methods. No there are no console errors in neither chrome, or firefox. (I was really hoping it would have errors like the common $ is not a function or whatever, but no console errors at all). I will make your first suggestion and see if it helps, even if it doesn't I appreciate your tip in helping me adopt better practices.

Comment: @VVV I will look into making a working fiddle, it may take me some time as I have some other things to do since I wasted so much time trying to fix this, but I will come back later with a fiddle, appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, ping me in a comment when you update your question with the fiddle. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Is that snippet initialized in the jquery ready function `$(function(){<your snippet>});`

Comment: @VVV Hey, I made a fiddle and added it to the bottom of the question. It works (Like my local one, works). Don't even know how to move forward as no console errors or anything out of ordinary seemingly on live server. And all the other jquery functionality works fine, even the color changing classes are working, its very specifically just the collapse functionality that seems to be having the issues... so confused...

Comment: @fnostro Yes it is